# PHPWord Reading more than docx from database to generate new docx

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

I'm trying to read 2 docx files or more from database and write all of it in new docx and may add text after
but it only read one file and don't even read the text below the loop
i'm new to php and phpword
i'm using netbean IDE 8.0.2

this is my code:

```php
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang($languageEnGb);

try {
    include ('DbConnection.php');

    $GenratedFileID = "1";
    $GenFileName = '';
    $sql = "SELECT S.FileID as fileID, G.GenratedFileName as GenFile, L.FileName 
 as Fname , L.FilePath as FilePth,"
        . "G.GenratedFileName as GName "
        . "FROM sections S,genratedfiles G, fileslibrary L "
        . " where G.GenratedFileID = S.GenratedFileID "
        . "and S.FileID = L.FileID and G.GenratedFileID =" . 
    $GenratedFileID;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {            //Read Library File
            $GenFileName = $row['GName'];
            $name = str_replace('/', '\\', $row['FilePth']);
            $source = __DIR__ . "\\{$name}";

            $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);
        }//end of while loop
        //  $section->addOLEObject($row['FilePth']);
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        $section->addTitle('Welcome to first database Genrated File', 1);
        $section->addText('created by me');
        $section->addTextBreak(2);


        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $objWriter->save('Generated Files/' . $GenFileName . '.docx');
    }
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```